# ¿Cómo declaro un arreglo de bytes en java?

Tags: java, android

Estoy recibiendo una serie de bytes en una app de android programada en java y necesito almacenar una respuesta de bytes pero esta respuesta no siempre va a ser de un mismo tamaño por el momento el código esta así

```
    byte[] Frame_Response = new byte[14];
    onRecivedData(Frame_Response);
```

El método onReciveData() necesita el Arreglo de byte donde se almacenara la cadena de bytes, para este ejemplo utilizo un ArrayByte de 14 posiciones pero el tamaño que uso como ejemplo es porque se el tamaño de la respuesta.

Lo que quiero es mandar un ArrayByte que el método lo reciba y no necesite especificarle cuantas posiciones.

A continuación el método onReciveData()

```
   private void onRecivedData(byte[] Destino){
    UsbSerialPort port = portU;
    try {
        int ReadBytes = port.read(Destino,0);

        if (ReadBytes != 0){
            String FResponse = bytesToHex(Destino);
            Response.setText(FResponse);
            Log.i(TAG,"Lectura de "+FResponse+" Exitosa");
            Status = false;
        }else{
            Log.i(TAG,"Falla en la Lectura");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(TAG,"Error "+ e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Interpretación

El método utiliza el byte destino para almacenar la respuesta pero dicho ArrayByte debe tener un tamaño fijo para cada caso.

¿Cómo lo declaro para que el tamaño se ajuste a la respuesta y no la respuesta se ajuste al tamaño?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pues quizás te puedan servir de utilidad los ArrayList, en este caso un ArrayList Byte por ejemplo, que vas añadiendo los Bytes que vayas necesitando.

Con algo así:

```
ArrayList<Byte> Frame_Response = new ArrayList<>(); //declaración
Frame_Response.add("byte"); // Para añadir la información que necesites
```

Y si por narices quieres pasar un Array de Bytes a la función siempre podrías crear un nuevo ArrayByte del tamaño del ArrayList y convertir el ArrayList en un ArrayByte, tal que así:

```
byte[] New_Frame_Response = new byte[Frame_Response.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < Frame_Response.size(); i++) {
    New_Frame_Response[i] = (byte) Frame_Response.get(i);
}
```